# .val() or focus() don't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple script: when you paste a link to some image in INPUT of the form, it automatically shows its preview:

[image]

But when I paste the same link not vie ctrl+C/ctrl+V with hands but through jQuery, my preview block remains empty:

```html
<input class="inputlink" type="text" ng-model="openImageUrl" ng-change="showImagePreview(openImageUrl)" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.vk_photo_edit').focus();
  $('.inputlink').val('http://name.com/image.jpg');
});
```

[image]

What can be wrong with the script?

Comment: Changing an input value programmatically never triggers any events regardless of library or framework used. Why are you using jQuery in the first place?

Comment: Why are you not updating the scope variable? What's the point of using AngularJS if you're writing such code?

Comment: What @TJ wrote is so painfully correct! Just stick with jQuery and DOM manipulation instead of using AngularJS

Comment: @IgorZuev You need to use `change()` to firing change event.

Answer (score -1):

`<input class="inputlink" type="text" ng-model="openImageUrl" ng-change="showImagePreview(openImageUrl)" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">`

`ng-change` activate  with the change event. This event is not triggered if you change the value from inside the script.

2 Solution

1. call the showImagePreview function directly
2. create a fake event with `document.createEvent`

Comment: Simpler to just `.trigger('input')` chained to setting value